# Arduino read last line from SD Card

Tags: arduino, sd-card, arduino-c++

I am pretty new to Arduino business. How do I read the last line from a SD Card? With following code snippet I can read the first line (all characters before "\n"). Now I would like to include a "backwards" statement (or something).

My code so far:

```
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>
File SD_File;
int pinCS = 10;
char cr;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SD.begin();

  SD_File = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);  
  SD_File.println("hello");
  SD_File.close();

  SD_File = SD.open("test.txt");
  while(true){
    cr = SD_File.read();
    if((cr == '\n') && ("LAST LINE?"))
        break;
    Serial.print(cr);
    }
  SD_File.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [methods of class File](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SD) like `seek` and `position` and methods of base class for File [the Stream class](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/stream/), for example method `find`.

Method `seek` sets the reading or writing position for the opened file.

```
  File file = SD.open("datalog.txt");
  if (file) {
    uint32_t lineStart = 0;
    while (file.available()) {
      lineStart = file.position();
      if (!file.find((char*) "\n"))
        break;
    }
    file.seek(lineStart);
    while (file.available()) {
        Serial.write(file.read());
    }
    file.close();
  } else {
    Serial.println("error opening datalog.txt");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a faster method, reading the whole file can be quite slow when dealing with large files.

```
// rewinds the file to the last occurrence of char c.
// returns 0 on error

int reverseFind(File& f, char c)
{
    for(unsigned long pos = f.position(); pos != 0 && f.seek(pos); --pos)
    {
        int rd = f.peek();
        if (rd < 0)
            return 0;

        // found! 
        if (rd == (c & 0xFF))
            return 1;
    }
    return (f.peek() == (c & 0xFF));
}

// seeks to the beginning of th elast line in the file.
// returns 0 on error.
int seekLastLine(File& f)
{
    if (!file.seek(f.size() - 2))  // -2 because last line could have a line ending..
        return 0;

    // find end of previous line.    
    if (reverseFind(f, '\n'))
        return (f.read() != -1); // move forward to beginning of line

    // if we're at beginning of file, then the first line is the last line.
    if (f.position() == 0)
        return 1;
        
   // we should logically never reach unless there was some I/O error.
   return 0;
}
```

Usage:

```
File f;
char buf[32];

if (seekLastLine(f))
{
    unsigned long len = f.size() - f.position();
    if (len > 32)
    {
        // ERROR! our read buffer is too small.
    }
    else if (!f.read(buf, len))
    {
        // deal with/log I/0 error...
    }
    else
    {
        // do something with line of data in buf.
    }
}
```